# Get url image with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
<article id="content">
  <img src="../anh-1.jpg">
  <img src="../anh-2.jpg">
  <img src="../anh-3.jpg">
</article>
```

how to get the url of the three pics with javascript ?

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: "I want to...." isn't a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) in case you have multipe nested images in different id's.
Then you could use [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) to get the image elements and loop those using a for loop and storing the `src` in an array `urls`.

```js
var elms = document.getElementById('content').getElementsByTagName('img');
var urls = [];
for (var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
    urls.push(elms[i].src);
}
console.log(urls);
```

```html
<article id="content">
    <img src="../anh-1.jpg">
    <img src="../anh-2.jpg">
    <img src="../anh-3.jpg">
</article>
<article id="content2">
    <img src="../anh-4.jpg">
    <img src="../anh-5.jpg">
    <img src="../anh-6.jpg">
</article>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

var urls = Array.prototype.slice.call(images).map(function(i) {
  return i.src;
})

console.log(urls);
```

```html
<article id="content">
  <img src="../anh-1.jpg" />
  <img src="../anh-2.jpg" />
  <img src="../anh-3.jpg" />
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const images = document.getElementById('content')[0].children; // will give you an array of the <img/> elements
```

And then you can access it's src property to get the urls. 
like:

```
const url = images.map((img) => {
   console.log(img.src);
   return img.src;
});
```